# Mobile Safari - Does javascript still run even when safari app is "minimized"

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, accelerometer

If I load a page in mobile Safari and then minimize (not close) Safari, will javascript code still execute?

I'm looking for a web-based solution of notifying when the phone is rotated. IOS 4.2+ (Safari) supports [JavaScript objects and event handlers](http://www.albertosarullo.com/blog/javascript-accelerometer-demo-source/%20%22JavaScript%20objects%20and%20event%20handlers) which allow for web-based accelerator functionality.

The question here is whether notifications ( alert('Rotated'); ) will still fire even if Safari is minimized.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I appear to be getting some hits - If anything needs further clarification, please feel free to leave a comment. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: A simple test I use is creating elements and appending them to the DOM repeatedly, with a text node of the current time. Then you minimize for a while and see if it wrote all the way.

Comment: I don't know, I don't have a mobile device that can run Safari.
You might test yourself, it's really simple.